# Get Eloquent records "whereHas" relationship with more than "main model" count, and skipping the same amount of records of each relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models, **`Activity`** and **`Prospector`**. Prospectors **hasMany** Activities, and an Activity **belongsTo** a Prospector.

Now, I need to get all Activities where its Prospector has more than 2.000 "pending" Activities, skiping the first 2.000 (of each Prospector individually)

**Prospector Model:**

```php
class Prospector extends Model
{
  public function activity()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Activity::class);
  }
}
```

**Activity Model:**

```php
class Activity extends Model
{
  public function prospector()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Prospector::class);
  }
}
```

Prospector #1: has 2.040 activities
Prospector #2: has 1.800 activities
Prospector #3: has 2.350 activities

So far I have this:

```php
$activities = Activity::whereHas('prospector', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('activities', fn ($query) => $query->pending(), '>', 2000);
})
->latest();

$activities->count(); // 4.390
```

This brings me all the activites only from Prospector **#1** and **#3** (who has more than 2000 "pending" activities).

But now I have to skip the first 2.000 Activities of **each** Prospector.

The right result should be:

```php
// Only the latest 40 from Prospector #1
// Only the latest 350 from Prospector #2
$activities->count(); //390
```

I can't just use `->skip(2000)` at the and of the query because it will skip 2000 from all activities, not from the activities of each Prospector:

```php
$activities->count(); //2.390
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume a group by and a skip could solve your problems. Run your initial query, group by `prospector_id` and do you logic from there.

```
$activities->groupBy('prospector_id')
    ->each(function (Collection $activities, int $prospectorId) {
        dd($activities->skip(2000), $prospectorId); // only from the prospector with $prospectorId
    });
```

If you want to have a single collection with all activities over the 2000 limit, something like this would achieve it, utilizing `map` and `reduce`.

```
$activities->groupBy('prospector_id')
    ->map(function (Collection $activities, int $prospectorId) {
        return $activities->skip(2000); // only from the prospector with $prospectorId
    })->reduce(function (Collection $carry, $activities) {
        return $carry->concat($activities);
    }, collect());
```